# How to make wireframe from inside an object visible?

Tags: modifiers, objects, wireframe

I'm currently working on a Blender project that requires creating a model with an internal wireframe. This means the wireframe should be part of the model's internal structure, visible through the exterior. But when i use the wireframe modifier it only shows the external wireframe like an overlay. Can anybody help me?
[image: Model with internal wireframe]

[image: Model with added wireframe modifier only showing external wireframe]

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want the edges as real geometry like the wireframe on the outer edges? In this case I'd go with the answer by @moonboots - just asking in case you only wanted some kind of overlay in the final render. By the way, sorry for how McLane killed your brother Hans.

Comment: no i need the wireframe on the inside as real geometry. I will ask a more specific question that goes more in detail in a bit. So that the purpose gets more clear. Just wanted to get the general understanding first, and also wanted to help keep this platform clear and clean for others to search for similar problems. It's about 3d printing and needed support... 
And Thank you for your condolences. (thats my actual name haha)

Comment: The wireframe modifier creates wire from the edges of faces, you need to add interior faces for it to work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/416IH.png however you'll see that the inner wires are messed up as this is not really supported. Suggest taking the skin route as illustrated by moonboots

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *Skin* modifier instead, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to thicken the edges in *Edit* mode:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! and sorry for the rookie question. But maybe it will help other newbies as well.